# How do I fix a water pipe leak?

Tags: water, pipe, smell

My dog has a leash that is by our back porch. About 3 feet over, there's a pipe that goes into the ground. One day she got her leash wrapped around it and started pulling at it. Ever since then, there's been a giant puddle in that area. It emits a nasty sewage-like smell, but it's a pipe that runs from the kitchen. I'm not entirely sure what to do about it or how to go about fixing it. It's becoming a major issue, but I sense that it is an easy fix if I just know how to go about it. Any help?

Comment: What is the pipe made of (metal, plastic, etc.)? How big is it? Some photos b might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

With out a more detailed description of the pipe it will be difficult to answer precisely, but here is a general, "good for most" answer. Since you can detect a sewer odor you can assume the pipe is either a vent or a drain for the kitchen. I'll also assume that it is a plastic (ABS) pipe as you stated it broke after it was pulled on (unless it is very weak iron?). Either  way the repair is straight forward. You must cut the damaged section out so that when removed you will have sound sections of pipe to fit the repair too. It is probably 2 inch diameter ABS. Purchase (2) rubber pipe connectors (they should have hose clamps on them) and a length of pipe (ABS) the size of the damaged pipe. Slip one coupler on the new section and the other to the existing pipe (use dish soap as a lubricant). hand tighten and check for drips.